# cin>>str causing "Unhandled exception (ntdll.dll) Access violation reading ..."

Tags: c++, string

I was using VS2012 Ultimate to Debug a simple testing project Tester2, which contains only one source file Source.cpp:

```
//Source.cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string s;
    cin>>s;
    return 0;
//Error occurrs after this line.
}
```

Error message:
[image: Error Message Window]

Then it leads me to a file called xdebug:
[image: xdebug]

Call Stack:
[image: Call Stack]

After setting breakpoints I found that the error occurs after the line "return 0".

I guess it is some pointer deleted at the end hasn't been allocated anything before... But I have no idea how to solve it.

Same error occurs on VS2010.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: compiles and runs fine on my vs2015

Comment: Did you provide a valid string to `cin`?

Comment: Are you sure you don't have some static variables that are destructed as you leave the program and cause the error? Did you expect the error with the exact code as above?

Comment: Could you please post the complete Call Stack of your exception?

Comment: ntdll.dll is known for a lot of crashes of different types, it seems like a buggy library. If you google "nrdll.dll crashes" you will find a lot different reasons.

Comment: @bornruffians yes I guess. even inputting a single letter will trigger the error.

Comment: @SimonKraemer I don't think I created any other variable except the string s. The code above is exactly the same in my project, and that why I call it a simple project..

Comment: @SimonKraemer Call Stack has been posted. Thanks again

Comment: Did you try clean & rebuild?

Comment: @Lol4t0 I tried just now but it doesn't work :(

Comment: @blade: NTDLL.DLL is fine. The problems with it are caused by developers who write bad code that corrupt memory and don't catch the problem, and when it finally causes an AV the location is in NTDLL's address space. NTDLL isn't buggy.

Comment: Did you start with an Empty project when making this, or one of the templates (i.e. "Windows Console App")?  Also, does the exception occur when compiling for Release as well as Debug?

Comment: @bornruffians It's an Empty project. Well I just built an Tester2.exe from the project and ran it, and a few seconds after I input a string a window came up saying "Tester2.exe has stopped working... Debug or Close Program"